# Win32 Alter Menu In Code

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, winapi, menuitem

I dont do a lot of windows programming but I cant seem to find out how to do this...

I have a toolbar for my application that will allow the user to switch certain functionality on and off. I have windows recognising when one of these toolbars are clicked however one of the options uses the "Checked" functionality.

The question is how do I know if this is current true or false in my code and also how do I set it to false in my code?

Basically I need this...

[image]

To look like this...

[image]

After the user clicks it

Code so Far...

```
switch (wmId)
        {
        case ID_SETTINGS_ENABLEGRAVITY:
            {
                MENUITEMINFO mii = { sizeof(MENUITEMINFO) };
                mii.fMask = MIIM_STATE;
                GetMenuItemInfo((HMENU)IDR_MENU1,ID_SETTINGS_ENABLEGRAVITY, FALSE, &mii);
                mii.fState ^= MFS_CHECKED;

                SetMenuItemInfo((HMENU)IDR_MENU1,ID_SETTINGS_ENABLEGRAVITY, FALSE, &mii);
                break;
            }
```

Thanks

Comment: Is this really raw Win32 or are you using MFC? Can you post a code snippet of how you are accessing your menu.

Comment: The menu was designed through Visual Studio 2010 Menu Editor and I use HiWords and loWords to establish if a change has been made. I can manually untick the box in the menu editor but I need the tick to go away when the user selects it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For Win32 you do this with the [`GetMenuItemInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647980.aspx) and [`SetMenuItemInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648001.aspx) functions:

```
MENUITEMINFO mii = { sizeof(MENUITEMINFO) };
mii.fMask = MIIM_STATE;
GetMenuItemInfo(hMenu, uItem, FALSE, &mii);
mii.fState ^= MFS_CHECKED;
SetMenuItemInfo(hMenu, uItem, FALSE, &mii);
```

This code toggles the checked property. It assumes that you are identifying the menu item by ID rather than position.

---

Looking at the code you posted, `(HMENU)IDR_MENU1` appears suspicious. I imagine that `IDR_MENU1` is an identifier rather than an `HMENU`. Casting is always a sign of a potential problem. If you don't have the `HMENU` to hand then call [`GetMenu`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647640.aspx) to obtain it.

In your code you should be testing the return value of the API calls and if they return `FALSE` then you should call `GetLastError` to obtain further information about the failure.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for that but I think I have done something wrong...Just to check show hMenu be IDR_MENU1 in my case? This is in the resource.h file. If it is then I cant seem to toggle the button

Comment: I'm not sure what more you want me to do. I have not got your code.

Comment: sorry, added the code above but not sure what else you would need?

Comment: Do the calls to `GetMenuItemInfo` and `SetMenuItemInfo` succeed? Do they return TRUE. If not what does GetLastError return? Actually, are you sure you should be casting `IDR_MENU1` to `HMENU`? If it really was `HMENU` then you would not need to cast surely. If you don't have the `HMENU` available as a variable then call `GetMenu` to obtain it.

Comment: Hey, Yeah there were errors I just used GetMenu() to obtain the HMENU and not the defines within the resource file.

Comment: And did that work? I'm desperate to know the outcome!  ;-)  OK, now I see you accepted (thanks) so I guess it did work.

Comment: The only decente explaination I found on the whole net on how to toggle a menu item. Many thanks.